# SQL: Regex to extract everything between first and last occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a table with a string column like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Column                                       | 
------------------------------------------------
| #Extract this# and #this too# do not extract |
------------------------------------------------
| Leave this and #get this out#                |
------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract everything from first # occurrence and the last # occurrence like this:

```
--------------------------------
| Expected Output              |
--------------------------------
| #Extract this and #this too# |
--------------------------------
| #get this out#               |
--------------------------------
```

I have tried
`regexp_substr(column, '#[^.]#', 1, regexp_count(column, '#'))` but it is giving me empty string.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check the answer and accept if it make sense

Answer (score 2):

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '#.*#') as pattern from [table]
```

[Demo for the regex output](https://regex101.com/r/kclYyo/1)

Answer (score 0):

I will use substring to get the first and last occurrence of #. I added +2 in the length of the string because we want to include #.

```
SELECT 
  substring(col 
           from 
              position('#' in col)  
           for 
              length(col) - position('#' in reverse(col)) - position('#' in col) + 2) 
FROM 
    table;
```

Result:

| substring |
| --- |
| #Extract this# and #this too# |
| #get this out# |